# CMake's find_package with header only libraries

Tags: boost, cmake, build-system

I have learned how to use find_package in CMake recently and I noticed that it works only with pre-compiled libraries.

This line works as expected:

```
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS filesystem REQUIRED)
```

If it is successful I can use something like that later:

```
target_link_libraries(target Boost::filesystem)
```

Using interfaces make it really easy to link all necessary dependendcies required by Boost.Filesystem. But it would be great to have similar solution for header-only libraries like Boost.Asio (I know that it is possible to build it into separate object but for example purposes I will treat it as header-only library)

```
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS asio REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(target Boost::asio)
```

And this won't work as expected.

Implementation of ASIO requires us to link `pthread` on UNIX-like systems so we can say that this library has a dependency which is thread library. Is there any convinient solution to use it in the same manner as Boost.Filesystem in CMake?

Comment: "Is there any convinient solution to use it in the same manner as Boost.Filesystem in CMake?" - You may create an INTERFACE library. Its main difference from IMPORTED target, like Boost.Filesystem, is absence of `IMPORTED_LOCATION` property. Exactly this differs a header-only library from a normal one.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `find_package` to find header-only dependencies by not specifying a target, see [FindBoost](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html), i.e.:

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
if(Boost_FOUND)
  include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
else()
  message(STATUS "Boost NOT Found !")
endif(Boost_FOUND)
```

However, you'll find that `Boost::asio` is header only but it requires `Boost::system`.
Therefore, you require:

```
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system REQUIRED)
if(Boost_FOUND)
  include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  target_link_libraries(target Boost::system)
else()
  message(STATUS "Boost NOT Found !")
endif(Boost_FOUND)
```

Comment: So what is the purpose of Boost::boost? How can I use it? I like imported targets, because I don't have to care about library dependencies. Can you provide some example use case of Boost::boost? It would be great to have something like Boost::asio and don't care about Boost::system at all.

Comment: What is more, first example which you have provided does not work for me.

`No header defined for boost; skipping header check`

Comment: I'm sorry that the first example didn't work for you. According to the link I gave `Boost::boost` is an alias for `Boost:headers` so you could try `find_package(Boost COMPONENTS headers REQUIRED)` instead. It is possible to use `boost::asio` without `boost::system`  by defining the macro `BOOST_ERROR_CODE_HEADER_ONLY` or by using the `asio` library from https://think-async.com/Asio/

Comment: It does not work for both boost and headers. That is why I don't understand its purpose.

Comment: @KasataAta I agree with you. The original answer I gave no longer works for me, despite following the cmake documentation!. I've amended it to what works now.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying this recently with headers only Boost and found that this works for Asio as a header only library.

```
find_package(BOOST)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Boost::headers pthread)
```

I found that despite it being header only if you do not include something in the
target_link_libraries then the include directories are not automatically included.  Don't know why that is the case but that is what I have seen.